Screen Recording At Scale
I am exploring options for creating a Docker image that I intend to deploy on AWS Lambda. This image needs to be lightweight and capable of being launched up to 100 times per day (duration ~ 30 seconds). Each instance will perform the following tasks:

Spin up a local server to serve basic HTML, CSS, and JavaScript content, which will display a simple animation lasting for 30 seconds (the animation is specific to input data).
Record a specific portion of the webpage, ideally targeting a div by its ID, for the duration of the animation.

I have considered using Manim but found it to be resource-intensive and potentially unsuitable for cloud deployment. Although I am not experienced with Node.js, Puppeteer has frequently appeared in my research.
Could you provide any recommendations or insights on how to achieve this effectively?
Best regards,
Andy
